# C - Storing pointers with malloc() in an array, can't free() them afterwards

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I want to store `pointers` that have been allocated using `malloc()` in an `array` and then `free` all of them after. However even though the program doesn't complain it doesn't work. Below `cleanMemManager()` won't actually `free` the memory as when tested inside `main()` the char* `pointer` is not `NULL` and it will print `???`.

**code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void **ptrList = NULL;

void tfree(void** ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}

void* talloc(int size)
{
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    ptrList[0] = ptr;   ///No clue if this actually does what I think it does
    return ptrList[0];
}

void initMemManager()
{
    ptrList = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void**) * 3);
    memset(ptrList, 0, sizeof(void**) * 3);
}

void cleanMemManager()
{
    tfree(&ptrList[0]); //Doesn't free the right pointer it seems
}

int main()
{
    initMemManager();
    char* ptr = (char*)talloc(3);
    cleanMemManager();

    if (ptr != NULL) //This will trigger and I'm not expecting it to
        printf("???");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the syntax to use for this, does the pointer not actually get touched at all? What is it freeing then since it doesn't throw any errors?

Comment: regarding: `void* ptr = malloc(size);`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the function `malloc()` is expecting a parameter with the type `size_t` not `int`.  (this implicit conversion can fail as `size_t` is unsigned and `int` is signed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `main`, `char *ptr = (char*)talloc(3);` declares `ptr` to be a local variable. It contains a copy of the value returned by `talloc`, and none of your subroutines know about `ptr` or where it is. So none of them change the value of `ptr`. Thus, when you reach `if (ptr != NULL)`, the value of `ptr` has not changed.

Additionally:

- In `initMemManager`, you should use `sizeof(void *)` in two places where you have `sizeof(void**)`. In these places, you are allocating and copying `void *` objects, not `void **` objects.
- It looks like you are trying to implement a sort of smart memory manager that automatically sets pointers to `NULL` when they are freed. To do that in C, you would have to give up having copies of pointers. For example, `ptr` is a copy of `ptrList[0]`, but `tfree` only sets whichever copy it is passed to `NULL`. We could give advice on building such a system, but it would quickly become cumbersome—your memory manager needs to keep a database of pointers and their copies (and pointers derived from them, as by doing array arithmetic). Or you have to refer to everything indirectly through that `ptrList` array, which adds some mess to your source code. Unfortunately, C is not a good language for this.

Comment: Yeah the sizeof(void*) thing was my bad, I was messing around with a triple pointer and forgot to revert it back. Thanks for the rest of the information.

Answer (score 3):

Freeing doesn't guarantee that pointers pointing to the allocated block will be set to NULL. If you actually try doing

```
if (ptrList[0] != NULL)
      printf("ptrList[0] != NULL");
```

you will see that the program won't output and if you remove the `cleanMemManager()` function call, it will output. This means `tfree` function is working as intended, it's freeing the memory that was allocated.

Now as to why `ptr` variable being not set to NULL, it's simply because `ptr` is still storing the old address. `cleanMemManager()` has no way of mutating the variable `ptr`. This is commonly called dangling pointer or use after free.

Also `free()` doesn't clean/zero out the the allocated space, the block is simply marked as "free". The data will most likely remain in the memory for a moment until the free block is overwritten by another `malloc` request.